# Server dropping local connections

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, debian

I have in my Debian server two applications running under Apache, one in PHP and other in Ruby on Rails. The PHP page makes a lot of calls to the running Ruby on Rails app, it calls file_get_contents on a url like `http://localhost/example.json`.

The problem is, after a while (usually some days) it simply stops working, everytime I try a local connection it's dropped. If I try to connect to localhost on another service (like ssh), it works normally, and, if I try to connect to my rails app from outside that server, it works normally too.

To solve this, I have to reboot the server (sometimes more than once) to work properly. It seems to me that the server is blocking itself somehow, but there was nothing odd on /var/log/messages (which is where iptables logs things, right?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I do a file_get_contents I run it with a void

```
$result = @file_get_contents
if(! $result) { // error

}
```

This makes sure your code doesn't hang on the function if (for instance) the file is not reachable.

That being said, I never had it lock my server. It only makes sure that the rest of my code runs as it should. It could be that your server hangs because something wants that data. However the result should not be this dramatic.

I hope this helps a bit at least. I'm curious to hear what you came up with.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using @ in front of file_get_contents, but that doesn't solve my problem, just ignores it. And it doesn't hangs either, it simple drops the connection, like if I try to access a closed port on my server.